# Order and filter multidimensional array

Tags: php

I need to catch the older people in each country with this multidimensional array

```
$arrayPersonas = array(
    array('id'=> "0AB239", 'country' => 1, 'firstname' => "Ernest"  , 'surname' => "Austin", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "12A179", 'country' => 0, 'firstname' => "Frances", 'surname' => "Poole", 'age' => 23),
    array('id'=> "1A90B9", 'country' => 1, 'firstname' => "Jacob", 'surname' => "Matthews", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "227FF9", 'country' => 2, 'firstname' => "Mina", 'surname' => "Day", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "2A6F39", 'country' => 3, 'firstname' => "Earl", 'surname' => "Mills", 'age' => 20),
    array('id'=> "325E79", 'country' => 4, 'firstname' => "Dennis", 'surname' => "Ray", 'age' => 33),
    array('id'=> "32E478", 'country' => 4, 'firstname' => "Alex", 'surname' => "Fery", 'age' => 33),
    array('id'=> "3A4DB9", 'country' => 5, 'firstname' => "Rhoda", 'surname' => "Conner", 'age' => 35));
```

I would also have to show all the content of that array, since I must show the ID, Country, Firstname, etc.

I tried to sort by country and then take the oldest person, but I failed

```
function filtrar_por($data){
array_filter($data, function( $var ){
  for($i=0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    switch ($i) {
      case 0:
        $country0 = $var['country'] == $i;
        $country0 = ordenar_por($country0);
        echo $country0;
        break;
      case 1:
        $country1 = $var['country'] == $i;
        break;
      case 2:
        $country2 = $var['country'] == $i;
        break;
      case 3:
        $country3 = $var['country'] == $i;
        break;
      case 4:
        $country4 = $var['country'] == $i;
        break;
      case 5:
        $country5 = $var['country'] == $i;
        break;
    }        
  }
});
}

  function ordenar_por($data){
    foreach ($data as $clave => $fila) {
      $orden1[$clave] = $fila['age'];
    }
    array_multisort($orden1, SORT_DESC, $data);
    return $data;
  }
```

I try with this to see if is working, but nothing.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: What exactly you need the result to be? you need to know only whos the older? or sort the array from older to younger?

Comment: function ordenar_por($data){
    foreach ($data as $clave => $fila) {
      $orden1[$clave] = $fila['age'];
    }
    array_multisort($orden1, SORT_DESC, $data);
    return $data;
  }

Comment: @BurhanKashour i need to show only the older with all information and order by ID

Comment: @CornelRaiu edited on main post

Comment: Posted answer, if nothing clear please ask me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using usort like the following:

```
<?php

$arrayPersonas = array(
    array('id'=> "0AB239", 'country' => 1, 'firstname' => "Ernest"  , 'surname' => "Austin", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "12A179", 'country' => 0, 'firstname' => "Frances", 'surname' => "Poole", 'age' => 23),
    array('id'=> "1A90B9", 'country' => 1, 'firstname' => "Jacob", 'surname' => "Matthews", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "227FF9", 'country' => 2, 'firstname' => "Mina", 'surname' => "Day", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "2A6F39", 'country' => 3, 'firstname' => "Earl", 'surname' => "Mills", 'age' => 40),
    array('id'=> "325E79", 'country' => 4, 'firstname' => "Dennis", 'surname' => "Ray", 'age' => 33),
    array('id'=> "32E478", 'country' => 4, 'firstname' => "Alex", 'surname' => "Fery", 'age' => 50),
    array('id'=> "3A4DB9", 'country' => 5, 'firstname' => "Rhoda", 'surname' => "Conner", 'age' => 35));
    
$final_data = array();
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['age'] + $b['age'];
}

foreach( $arrayPersonas as $person){
    if(!empty($final_data[$person['country']])){
        foreach( $final_data[$person['country']] as $key => $value ){
            if( $final_data[$person['country']][$key]['age'] < $person['age'] ){
                unset($final_data[$person['country']][$key]);
                $final_data[$person['country']][] = $person;
            }else if( $final_data[$person['country']][$key]['age'] == $person['age'] ){
                $final_data[$person['country']][] = $person;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $final_data[$person['country']][] = $person;
        usort($final_data[$person['country']], 'sortByOrder');
    }
}
print_r($final_data);
```

Code Snippet Sandbox : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ffed1ebb2940fc71cd35cb8bfddae2e8ca3077c

Comment: Thanks, but i need to show each older from each country

Comment: @Zano you said `i need to show only the older with all information and order by ID`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. On main post, the first line i explain that.

Comment: @Zano Updated please take a look!

Comment: For example, Country 1 have 2 person with same year, how can you show both?

Comment: Just add `else if` `age = age` then add to the array, update the answer and the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

i have another way to find the result you want. It's maybe a little less efficient than Burhan anwser, but i think it's more readable.

```
<?php

$persons = array(
    array('id'=> "0AB239", 'country' => 1, 'firstname' => "Ernest"  , 'surname' => "Austin", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "12A179", 'country' => 0, 'firstname' => "Frances", 'surname' => "Poole", 'age' => 23),
    array('id'=> "1A90B9", 'country' => 1, 'firstname' => "Jacob", 'surname' => "Matthews", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "227FF9", 'country' => 2, 'firstname' => "Mina", 'surname' => "Day", 'age' => 30),
    array('id'=> "2A6F39", 'country' => 3, 'firstname' => "Earl", 'surname' => "Mills", 'age' => 20),
    array('id'=> "325E79", 'country' => 4, 'firstname' => "Dennis", 'surname' => "Ray", 'age' => 33),
    array('id'=> "32E478", 'country' => 4, 'firstname' => "Alex", 'surname' => "Fery", 'age' => 50),
    array('id'=> "3A4DB9", 'country' => 5, 'firstname' => "Rhoda", 'surname' => "Conner", 'age' => 35)
);
    
    // Get the different countries you can have
    $differentCountries = array_unique(array_column($persons, "country"));
    
    $result = [];
    
    
    // Loop over the different contries
    foreach ($differentCountries as $countryId) {
        
        // Get the all values for this specific country
        $valuesForThisCountry = array_filter($persons, function ($person) use ($countryId) {
            return $person["country"] == $countryId;
        });
        
        // Get an associative array with "id" as key and "age" as value
        $formattedArray = array_column($valuesForThisCountry, "age", "id");

        // Get the older ones
        $olders = array_keys($formattedArray, max($formattedArray));
        
        // Get the initial values of persons you found
        $personsById = array_filter($persons, function ($person) use ($olders) {
            // Check if the "id" is in the $olders
            return in_array($person["id"], $olders);
        });
        
        // Finally, put the result in the $result array
        $result = array_merge($result, $personsById);
        
    }
    
    
    print_r($result);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/464bf5fa58f75bdecbf85f49edfecefd3df90673

EDIT : As anwsered Burhan Kashour, I edit the code (juste the last merge line is edited)

This is the new version http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb757dc7ae4862f6ac671f0cb36e057f18a8ced6

Comment: Still this don't answer the full question as he asked, he wants the full array to be indexed as countries arrays , each country is an array for the older age, and if there is same age in the same country, so you should add them to the array aswell

Comment: I updated the code snippet, i think this time is the right ;)